# SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync-NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

using com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0

> class extend FragmentActivity

```
private void setMap()
            {

                map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2)).getMap();
                ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                        map = googleMap;
                    }
                });

                if (map !=null )
                {
                    zoom = 16;

                    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL); 
                    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 
                    UiSettings uis = map.getUiSettings();
                    uis.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);  
                    uis.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true); 
                    uis.setScrollGesturesEnabled(true); 
                    uis.setZoomGesturesEnabled(true); 



                    String snippet = "";

                    for ( int i = 0 ; i < fe.length ;i++){

                        latitude = fe[i].getEastlongitude();
                        longitude = fe[i].getNorthernlongitude();

            if (latitude== 0)
                continue;

            addr = new LatLng (latitude, longitude);
            MarkerOptions mk = new MarkerOptions();
            mk.position(addr);
            mk.title(fe[i].getTitle());
            snippet = fe[i].getAddress();
            mk.snippet(snippet);
            mk.draggable(true);
            map.addMarker(mk);
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL); // Normal MapView

            if (index == i)
            {

                address = addr;
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(addr, zoom));
            }

        }


    }
}
```

I get

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)'
>   on a null object reference

[enter image  here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw8lF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I think you're using an invalid resource id 
Change the following line

```
((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync()
```

like this

```
((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id. fragment2)).getMapAsync()
```

Hope you understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you call getMap() in onCreateView, try using onViewCreated() instead.

Try using getChildFragmentManager()

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Last option, you can try MapView

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.onResume();
mapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: My class extend FragmentActivity

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the **onCreateView** method then you must be using Fragments, according to [this](http://androiddhina.blogspot.com/2017/11/how-to-use-google-map-in-fragment.html):

> In the latest update of Google for Maps, only MapView is supported for fragments.

So, in your XML instead of using a map fragment, use a MapView:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Then in your fragment's **onCreateView**:

```
mMapView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
try {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

Also, according to [MapView docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView):

> Users of this class must forward all the life cycle methods from the Activity or Fragment containing this view to the corresponding ones in this class. In particular, you must forward on the following methods:
>
> - onCreate(Bundle)
> - onStart()
> - onResume()
> - onPause()
> - onStop()
> - onDestroy()
> - onSaveInstanceState()
> - onLowMemory()

Answer (score 0):

Modified some fragment's setting and
Using new api key is solved.